# Building a calendar in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a calendar in Java with an event function that has:

- Time
- Date
- Title
- Category

I just dont know how I can access my `ArrayList` and alter the data:

```
 public class termin{
        
       private LocalDate Date; 
       private LocalTime Time;
       private String Titel;   
       private String Kategorie;
       private List<Person> Teilnehmer = new ArrayList<Person>();
     // Teilnehmer.add(new Person("Thomas", "Nero"));
    
        public termin(LocalDate Date, LocalTime Time, String Titel, String Kategorie) {
            this.Date = Date;
            this.Time = Time;
            this.Titel = Titel;
            this.Kategorie = Kategorie;
        }
       
    
    // Person in a different class
    
    public class Person {
       
        private String vorname;
        private String nachname;
    
        public Person(String vorname, String nachname) {
            this.vorname = vorname;
            this.nachname = nachname;
           
        }
```

Comment: By convention, variable names in Java start with lowercase letter.

Comment: It depends on your design choice. For example, you could give each "termin" a reference to its calendar ... if really needed. It depends on what a "termin" should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `Teilnehmer` from anywhere within `termin`. If you need to access the list from elsewhere, e.g. from `Person` you will need a getter.

Seeing your commented out code the error is obvious - you are trying to call `add` - which is a **method** -  outside a method. This is not allowed as is described in most introductory Java tutorials. You can shift the call *e.g.* to a public method and call it from elsewhere:

```
// method definition in class "termin"
public void addPerson( Person person )
{
    Teilnehmer.add( person );
}

// elsewhere
termin.addPerson( new Person( "Thomas", "Nero" ) );
```

Also you **really really** should check up on variable naming conventions, otherwise you will face having to get used to the proper style if you ever happen to work on any collaborative project using Java. In its current form your code is hard to read, because the naming follows no conventions whatsoever.

Comment: That wasnt the question i  asked. My issue is that i dont understand how i would set time for example wihtout changing the rest

Comment: You asked no question at all, your entire post has zero question marks. The only thing in your post that can be construed as a question is the passage *I just dont know how I can access my ArrayList and alter the data:* which I answered.